# IIS 6 Windows Authentication Issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication, iis-6

The issue is I can't view the page using `Window Authentication`.

This is my steps.

I created a website in my server Windows Server 2003 IIS 6 with .Net Framework 2.

Then Inside the root folder, I created a folder. Let's call it "FolderA".

In "FolderA", I created a page. Let's call it "fileA.aspx".

The website is running fine. As I turn on the `Anonymous Access`.

But for "fileA.aspx", I need to turn on the `Window Authentication` coz I don't want everyone to go in and view that page.

So, I select "FolderA", go to `Properties`,

So, I turn off the `Anonymous Access` and make sure `Window Authentication` is turned on.

Then I browse from my PC. It prompted me the Login Diaglog Box.

I key in my credentials I used to log in for the server and I can access the page.

That is working fine.

However, when I view it from the server itself, it prompted me the Login Diaglog Box.

But when I key in my credentials, it is saying "Access Denied".

I even tried using Administrator credentials.

It is still access denied.

Is there any setting to set or anything to change in web.config?

Comment: Are you working on a domain or not?

Comment: Yup, I am working on a domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Review event logs on the server to see if you happen to hit this.

Comment: Ok. I will take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow authenticated users and deny not authenticated users?

```
<authorization>
 <allow users="*"/>
 <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```